# class sympy.core.add.Add convert to float

Tags: python, class, sympy

This part of program on Python uses SymPy library.
As a result it's produces a value in **sympy.core.add.Add** class which is not capable with other parts of the program.

```
from sympy import *
x = symbols('x')
y = 1 - (0.1 * coeff1) / (x + 2) - sin(x) * (2 * x + coeff1)
yprime = y.diff(x)
```

How to convert **sympy.core.add.Add** class to ordinary **float** or **int** in order to use variable **yprime** in further calculations?

Comment: Where does coeff1 come from? Please give full code to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about just ending your code with

yprime = float(yprime)

Answer (score 1):

I just found the solution.
using `yprime=float(yprime)` won't work because `yprime` is an element of a class of `numpy` only.
But you can transform that element in order to make the python standard language be capable to read it.

try:

```
yprime=str(yprime)

#this will transform yprime to a string

yprime=eval(yprime)

#this will return a float or a int object so you can do calculations without any problem but make sure that the constants are well defined.
```

Comment: It is a terrible workaround. Just terrible. You lose accuracy in such conversion.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can take a look at the documentation here http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/core.html#module-sympy.core.add
There are some functions starting with "as_" for the type sympy.core.add.Add, with which you can convert add.add into other formats and then change into float or int.